# how to restrict apk file to installe only from playstore

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

I want to know, Is it possible to restrict a apk to install only form play store and not by other way like if someone share apk file to friend then apk should not be install in his friend's device.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're developing a paid app, you can use the available [Purchase Status API](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/gp-purchase-status-api.html) for verifying the user's purchase status.

Furthermore, you can also try setting `allowBackup=false` in your Manifest file. Doing so will disable your app's backup and users won't be able to then share it with others.

According to the documents, "The allowBackup attribute determines if an application's data can be backed up and restored."

More info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#allowBackup